# Format problem categorizing time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert hours to an categoric format,
the column is like this with hundreds of entries.

```
hr_animals

21:25:00
10:36:00
23:17:00
01:23:00
NA
13:30:00
NA
```

And i want the output like this:

```
hr_animals

Night
Morning
Night
Dawn
NA
Afternoon
NA
```

I'm using this code to categorize the time:

```
pamdf ['part_of_day'] = (pamdf['hr_animals'].dt.hour % 24 + 4) // 4
pamdf['part_of_day'].replace({1: 'Dawn',
                      2: 'Early Morning',
                      3: 'Morning',
                      4: 'Noon',
                      5: 'Evening',
                      6: 'Night'}, inplace=True)
pamdf.head()
```

But i keep having this error:

`AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Ok, i get it. The format is wrong. As i checked the format of the column is an object:

```
pamdf['hr_animals'].describe()

count          139
unique         133
top       01:43:00
freq             2
Name: hr_animals, dtype: object
```

But everytime i try to convert it, i get a new error:

1th.

```
pamdf['hr_animals'] =  pd.to_datetime(pamdf['hr_animals']

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<ipython-input-33-6d6f40bdc27d>, line 2) 
  File "<ipython-input-33-6d6f40bdc27d>", line 2
    pamdf['hr_animals'] =  pd.to_datetime(pamdf['hr_animals']
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

2th

```
pamdf['hr_animals'] = pamdf['hr_animals'].astype('datetime64[ns]')


TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
```

3th

```
pamdf['hr_animals'] = pd.to_datetime(pamdf['hr_animals'], format='%H:%M').dt.hour

ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00
```

The fact is that i only want the hour to be converted. The date is in another column.
Here is a print of the dataset to help understand.

How can i do it?

Thanks in advance, i'm really breaking my head

-----EDIT---

By using the answer given, i get this:

[image]

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(pamdf['hr_animals'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').dt.hour` doesn't change your columns. You need to assign back `pamd['hr_animals'] = pd.to_datetime(...)`. But then again, avoid `apply` when possible.

Comment: `range(24,6)` is empty. Review your nested `if .. elif`. It can just be `if x <=6: return 'Dawn' elif x<=12: return 'Morning'`. Then again it's a really bad idea anyway :-).

Comment: Yeah! But i tried the answer and got all "NaN" and that function returns all nights. Between the cross and sword and getting nowhere hehehe. In fact, thank you so much for trying so hard to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because your data is not `datetime` type so you cannot use `.dt` access. To fix your code, the 3rd option should be:

```
pd.to_datetime(pamdf['hr_animals'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').dt.hour
```

That said, your format is better suited for `timedelta` instead of `DateTime`. Try:

```
df['hr_animals'] = ((pd.to_timedelta(df['hr_animals'], errors='coerce')
                      // pd.Timedelta('4H') )
                      .add(1)
                      .replace({1: 'Dawn',
                      2: 'Early Morning',
                      3: 'Morning',
                      4: 'Noon',
                      5: 'Evening',
                      6: 'Night'})
                   )
```

Output:

```
  hr_animals
0      Night
1    Morning
2      Night
3       Dawn
4        NaN
5       Noon
6        NaN
```

Another option is to use `pd.cut`, which returns a categorical column. This might be helpful because the labels will be ordered, i.e. `Dawn < Early Morning<...`:

```
df['hr_animals'] = pd.cut(pd.to_timedelta(df['hr_animals'], errors='coerce'),
                          bins = pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(0,25,4), unit='H'),
                          labels=['Dawn','Early Morning', 'Morning', 
                                  'Noon', 'Evening', 'Night']
                   )
```

Comment: I put some edits in the question! I used part of your code, but i guess the main problem is the format that i can't by any means get converted.